# How to format repeater column values to decimal values

Tags: asp.net, repeater

how to format  repeater column values to Decimal values.

I have used the following statement in my program

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BILLAMT")%>
```

The output I get are as follows.

`5122
12232
60085`

But instead I want the output as the following

`5122.00
12232.00
60085.00`

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround for the problem at hand. You could change the select statement so that you could get the desired output.
Consider the following.

`select convert(decimal(10,2), <column name>) from <table name>`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `Eval` item to numeric using `Convert` class, then in the `ToString()` method of that number, you can do your formatting.
For example:

```
<%# Convert.ToDouble(
    Eval("BILLAMT").ToString()
    ).ToString("your format string") %>
```